# Webpack - resolve-url-loader cannot operate: CSS error

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2, postcss

I have a Webpack config set up and running smoothly for my javascript, but when I try to add PostCSS to that same config, something starts going wrong. It actually works, and produces my CSS, but it's at the same time throwing some strange errors that I've had a really hard time with.

```
$ npm run env:dev -- webpack-dev-server
> arc@0.1.0 env:dev /Users/mattias/projects/pestbarn.github.io
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development "webpack-dev-server"

Project is running at http://localhost:3000/
webpack output is served from /

WARNING in ./src/postcss/base.postcss
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) resolve-url-loader cannot operate: CSS error
    ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'src/postcss/%3Cno%20source%3E'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:584:18)
    @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/postcss/base.postcss webpack/hot/only-dev-server

Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:

WARNING in ./~/css-loader?importLoaders=1!./~/resolve-url-loader!./~/postcss-loader/lib?sourceMap=inline!./src/postcss/base.postcss
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error)   resolve-url-loader cannot operate: CSS error
    ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/mattias/projects/pestbarn.github.io/src/postcss/%3Cno%20source%3E'
      at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:584:18)

webpack: Compiled with warnings.
```

**webpack.config.js**: (based on [Atomic React](https://github.com/diegohaz/arc/wiki/Webpack) by Diego Haz)

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const devServer = require('@webpack-blocks/dev-server2');
const splitVendor = require('webpack-blocks-split-vendor');
const happypack = require('webpack-blocks-happypack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const {
    addPlugins, createConfig, entryPoint, env, setOutput,
    sourceMaps, defineConstants, webpack
} = require('@webpack-blocks/webpack2');

const host = process.env.HOST || 'localhost';
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const sourceDir = process.env.SOURCE || 'src';
const publicPath = `/${process.env.PUBLIC_PATH || ''}/`.replace('//', '/');
const sourcePath = path.join(process.cwd(), sourceDir);
const outputPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

const babel = () => () => ({
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader' }
        ]
    }
});

const assets = () => () => ({
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.(png|jpe?g|svg|woff2?|ttf|eot)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=8000' }
        ]
    }
});

const postcssLoader = () => () => ({
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.postcss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    use: 'css-loader?importLoaders=1!resolve-url-loader!postcss-loader?sourceMap=inline'
                })
            }
        ]
    }
});

const resolveModules = modules => () => ({
    resolve: {
        modules: [].concat(modules, ['node_modules']),
    },
});

const config = createConfig([
    entryPoint({
        app: path.join(sourcePath, 'index.js'),
        'main.css': path.join(sourcePath, 'postcss/base.postcss')
    }),
    setOutput({
        filename: '[name]',
        path: outputPath,
        publicPath
    }),
    defineConstants({
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': process.env.NODE_ENV,
        'process.env.PUBLIC_PATH': publicPath.replace(/\/$/, '')
    }),
    postcssLoader(),
    addPlugins([
        new webpack.ProgressPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: path.join(process.cwd(), 'public/index.html')
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('main.css'),
    ]),
    happypack([
        babel()
    ]),
    assets(),
    resolveModules(sourceDir),

    env('development', [
        devServer({
            contentBase: 'public',
            stats: 'errors-only',
            historyApiFallback: { index: publicPath },
            headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
            host,
            port
        }),
        sourceMaps(),
        addPlugins([
            new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin()
        ]),
    ]),

    env('production', [
        splitVendor(),
        addPlugins([
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ compress: { warnings: false } }),
        ])
    ]),
]);

module.exports = config;
```

**postcss.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('postcss-cssnext'),
        require('precss'),
        require('postcss-font-magician'),
        require('postcss-automath')
    ]
};
```